# How to add a custom datepicker widget on the admin page in Django?

Tags: python, django, admin

this is my admin.py

```
class DeliveryLine(OrderLine):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

class DeliveryLineAdmin(OrderLineAdmin):
    def pickup_date(self,obj):
        widgets= AdminDateWidget()
        return widgets

    def pincodes(self,obj):

        ob=OrderHeader.objects.using('orders').values_list('billing_pincode').filter(order_id=obj.order_id)
        for tup in ob:
            for item in tup:
                return item 
        # item for value in ob :
            #   for ob in literal_eval(value)

    def billing_address(self ,obj):
        return  str(obj.seller_name)+'</br>'+str(obj.seller_address)+'</br>'

    billing_address.allow_tags=True



    list_display=('order_id','billing_address','product_qty','product_name','unit_price','seller_phone','pincodes','seller_name','seller_address','subtotal','pickup_date')
    search_fields=['pickup_date',]

admin.site.register(DeliveryLine,DeliveryLineAdmin)
```

OrderLine is some other model which i am inheriting in this deliveryline model so that i dont have to create another model deliveryline.

Now what i want to do is 
create a search field and when someone clicks on that field it opens a datepicker and selects date from that datepicker and django will perform its search on the basis of that.

Comment: You'll need to write some JS code and supply that JS file through `class Media`.

Comment: class DeliveryLineAdmin(OrderLineAdmin): def pickup_date(self,obj): widgets= AdminDateWidget() return widgets.. what about this admin date widget ...what's the use of this widget